# Laravel Form validation issue when form edit?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I used Laravel Form validation for validate form:

```
$rules = array(
    'user_name' => 'required|min:3|max:20|unique:users',
    'email' => 'required|email|max:50|unique:users',
    'mobile' => 'required'
);
```

this is working well on some thing add. but when i going to edit **unique:users** part given error "already  been taken", so how to write validation to **check exclude edit row**.

If I wrote this way, does it work?

```
$rules = array(
    'user_name' => 'required|min:3|max:20|unique:users,'.$id,
    'email' => 'required|email|max:50|unique:users,'.$id,
    'mobile' => 'required'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

@user3099298 Your second set of code looks alright.

```
$rules = array(
    'user_name' => 'required|min:3|max:20|unique:users,user_name,' . $user_id, // $user_id = Currently being edited user id.
    'email' => 'unique:users,email_address,' . $user_id, // $user_id = Currently being edited user id.
    'mobile' => 'required',
);
```

I have added column names in rules - may be you can try that one.

Please check here the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation#rule-unique)

Where they explain how to ignore some rules by providing ID.